# mobile version of a website

Tags: php, mobile, browser, version, opera

I am making a mobile version of my website but I am facing a problem. I googled a lot but I could not find anything. 
When I open the mobile version with opera mobile, the mobile version is as big as the screen and if I zoom it to 100%, it becames too big for the screen and I have to scroll to see the whole website like I am using the desktop version.
If I open the website with nokia browser, the mobile version fits the screen of my mobile and it looks cool.

Every suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Tried css media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into CSS Media Queries and the viewport meta tag.

Some info on it, especially from the point of view of developing for opera, can be found in these articles

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/the-mobile-web-optimization-guide/
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/love-your-devices-adaptive-web-design-with-media-queries-viewport-and-more/

I especially urge you to check out the article on viewport.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobilee](http://jquerymobile.com/) is nice tool to have mobile version of your site...